# Is there a way to have the administrator set the values used by the Outlook add-in in bulk?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

Is there a place where I can configure settings for add-ins (e.g., URLs for external communication used by add-ins) that are managed by the Microsoft365 Management Center, etc. in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

There are no settings as such for add-ins that you can configure externally. You can use the [Microsoft REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api) from add-ins to get what you need, or call an API to your own hosted endpoint.

You can save any add-in settings for an user using [Roaming Settings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.roamingsettings?view=outlook-js-preview)

Does this answer your question, or are you talking about some completely different use case?

Comment: thanks. For example, I want to securely store the client ID and client secret that needs to be kept in the client (Outlook) for Oauth authentication, is that possible?

Comment: For authentication you can either use getAccessToken or getCallbackTokenAsync APIs. 
Please refer following docs: 
getAccessToken: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins
getCallbackTokenAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#getCallbackTokenAsync_callback__userContext_